# I once installed an app requiring an Apple ID from the US store and now other apps require that Apple ID. Why?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, apple-id

I once needed an app which was only available in the US App Store, so I installed it using my US Apple ID. Now, months later when I want to update apps, many of them require the US Apple ID but even though that was NOT the Apple ID they were "purchased" with (most of these apps are free).

**I am 100% certain these apps were not downloaded with the US account**.

**My question:** How can iOS switch the ID used to purchase apps even though they were not downloaded with that particular account?

It's important to mention that as soon as I installed the US app I switched back to my normal Apple ID (and therefore the other store not being the US one).

This is not the first time I have seen this. I remember seeing this a few years back on an another iPhone.

Comment: Is this always happening or just sometimes? **Just thinking out aloud here:** Have you still got the app installed that was originally purchased via the US Apple ID? If so, is it possible that when you've got multiple updates you're just tapping on Update All and this particular app is one of the ones needing to be updated, and therefore you're being prompted for the US Apple ID and password because it wants to verify your credentials for that particular app?

Comment: Another possibility is that since you probably haven't used the US ID for a long time it's actually wanting you to log into it to verify a payment method or some other account detail.

Comment: @Monomeeth so yes first time i did Update all as i always to then it poped up so then i started some of the apps that did not require this account and then it amazed me when i got to some apps that i knew it required my normal AppleID account and not the US one so it doesn't do this on all apps, maybe it does this on apps that i may have "purchased" on both accounts (i can't recall whether i may have installed Skype for instance on the US account once for many years back but definitely know that the one i have now is NOT installed using the US appleID account.)

Comment: @Monomeeth Yes you are right that the AppleID does require to validate this US account now but why does it do that on apps not installed with that account, that's what puzzles me.

Comment: Ah, well, that's your answer then. If the US Apple ID does require some sort of validation, then it will prompt you for this whenever a device associated with that ID is using a service that is communicating with Apple's services (i.e. the App Store, iTunes, Apple Music, etc depending on the circumstances). So, for example, if you had a credit card on that ID and it's expired, then you'll get prompted about it simply by accessing something like the App Store. That's just one example. Even with no credit card you may need to verify your account (there are *many* reasons why this can happen).